# Use of asterisk * - Error 13 Mismatch - Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm struggling with the following issue: I'm trying to insert an asterisk (*) in a formula containing a vlookup function in VBA. I'm getting an error 13 mismatch and I don't know how to solve it. I suppose the format isn't good. Here is my code:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long     

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sht.Activate     
Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Value = _                        
     "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("*"&J2&"*",CDL_Greece!C:C,1,0)),J2, VLOOKUP("*"&J2&"*",CDL_Greece!C:C,1,0))"
```

I'v seen that we can use the character ~ that would allow to use this asterisk. But it doesn't work on my side.

Does anyone have any clues on this issue?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it will be `.formula`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""*""&J2&""*"",CDL_Greece!C:C,1,0)),J2,VLOOKUP(""*""&J2&""*"",CDL_Greece!C:C,1,0))"
```

If you want quotes `"` in your worksheet formula you need to use double quotes `""` in your code.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that works now! Big thanks for your quick reply :)